# java Regular expression while splitting a string over parenthesis

Tags: java, split

I have a `String` like

```
Move Selected Patients (38)
```

I want to retrieve `38` between the parenthesis using java split.

Tried with this code:

```
String a1 = "Move Selected Patients (38)";
String[] myStringArray = new String[2];
myStringArray = a1.split("(", 2);
System.out.println(myStringArray[0]);
```

and it fails with this exception:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 1.
```

Can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the paren as the split argument is still a regular expression: `\\(`.  Keep in mind that this will still return `38)` as the second element.  It would make more sense to use `Matcher` to capture the contents of the parentheses in a group: `\\((.*?)\\)`

Answer (score 2):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\(([0-9]*)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Move Selected Patients (38)");
String s = m.group(1);
```

If you need another part of the string as well, just use another group for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve the requirement with regex as shown below:

```
String str = "Move Selected Patients (38)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+)\\)");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(str);
while(match.find()) {
    System.out.println(match.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the code : Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+)\\)"); And why match.find() is needed

Comment: The inner round brackets are used to group elements in the pattern . We have to use "\\" to define a single backslash since it is an escape character in Java Strings. The \d indicates any digit, short for [0-9] and the match.find() attempts to find the next sub-sequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

`(` is a reserved char used for groups, you need to escape it with `\`

Answer (score 1):

`(` is regex metacharacter, you have to escape it using `\\`. Try with `\\(`.